# Google Apps script Sort

Tags: google-apps-script

Using App Scripts I've pulled all the headers in an array, strip out the text part and built an array of the below format:
`[1,10,23,45,7,12,76,88,9]`

Sample code:

```
var shHeader = sh.getRange(1, 3, 1, 20);
var shH1 = shHeader.getValues();
shH1 = shH1[0].sort();
```

When I do the normal `sort()` on the array, the order I'm getting is like:
`[1,10,12,23,45,7,76,88,9]`

I want sort to give me an output:
`[1,7,9,10,12,23,45,76,88]`

Can anyone help with any function or some easy hack to get my desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function into the sort method that takes two parameters.

```
shH1 = shH1[0].sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
```

Here is documentation to help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks Jordan! I couldn't see any documentation.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I meant to attach a link!